# Help needed Pausing/Resuming FadeIn and FadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hopefully this is a simple request. I found this code that will work perfectly for what I want to do (Rotate through list items while fading in and out) http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/S5Cjm/1/ . However, I am looking to have the animation pause on mouse over and resume on mouse out. I am a novice at the moment with Javascript and JQuery, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: Side questions: Is there a benefit to using JQuery to do this? Would a stand alone script be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attached the hover event to your list items. The over function stops the animation and all following animations using jQuery.stop(true). The out function resumes the animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/US4Fc/1/

```
var duration = 1000
function InOut(elem) {
    elem.delay(duration).fadeIn(duration).delay(duration).fadeOut(

    function() {
        if (elem.next().length > 0) {
            InOut(elem.next());
        }
        else {
            InOut(elem.siblings(':first'));
        }

    });
}

$(function() {
    $('#content li').hide().hover(
        function() {
            $(this).stop(true)
        },
        function() {
            var curOp = Number($(this).css("opacity"));
            $(this).fadeTo(duration*(1-curOp), 1, function() {
                InOut($(this)) 
            });

        }
    );
    InOut($('#content li:first'));

});
```

Comment: This is very close. However if I change the animation values (lets say 1000 for fadeIn and delay) and I mouse over/out during the animation it seems to reset the opacity of that particular list item to the opacity at the time of hover. So, if I mouse over/out as a list item is just beginning to fade in it will become essentially invisible. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Just had a thought. Is there an easy way to set opacity to 100% on hover? Would that solve the issue?

Comment: I updated the code so now it checks the current opacity when you hover out. It then determines how much longer the animation is supposed to last and completes the animation in that amount of time. Just set the duration variable first. For example, if the animation is 50% done, then the opacity will be 0.5. For a duration of 1000ms, the code will complete the animation from 0.5 to 1 in 500ms and then continue looping.

Comment: If you want to set the opacity to 100% on hover, just use $(this).css("opacity", 1). However, this would interrupt the animation. The solution I posted is more elegant.

Comment: Where exactly would I place $(this).css("opacity", 1)? My apologizes for being a js noob. Would $(this).css("opacity", 1) cause the list item to jump to 100% opacity if it was hovered over when it is fading out/in? Would it continue to fade out normally when no longer hovered? Your solution is elegant but I'm looking to use this a a news type ticker and would actually prefer it that the list item jump to full opacity if hovered. Also, does having the CSS Value of display:none for #content li effect the script performance? Thanks again, this is extremely close to what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Check out this fork. I added the opacity code to the first function in the hover: http://jsfiddle.net/pq2bM/1/. Now, when you hover over, it pauses the animation, and immediately jumps to 100% opacity.

Comment: This is the line where I set the opacity: $(this).stop(true).css("opacity", 1);

Answer (score 0):

[Will this work for you](http://jsfiddle.net/S5Cjm/49/)?

```
$(function(){
    var active;
    $('#content li').hide().hover(
        function(){
            active = $(this).stop();
        },
        function(){
            active && InOut(active);
        }
    );
    InOut( $('#content li:first') );

});
```

Comment: This seems to go haywire if the list item is hovered over before the fade animation is complete.